# First time inserting records by using linq

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a table with name "tbltrackuser" and below design"

```
Trackid (pk,identity)
Drafiid (bigint)
Userid (bigint)
Date (time)
```

I like to insert records by using linq in this table for specific user and draftid just first time, and 2 times or more automatically not inserted in the table.

```
Trackid     draftid     userid      date
 1              20      user1       01-jan-13
 2              30      user1       02-jan-13
 4              20      user2       01-jan-13
```

For example system automatically not inserted below record for draftid=20, user=user1 at 03-jan-13
Because has been inserted before at 01-jan-13

```
  Trackid       draftid     userid      date
    3       20      user1       03-jan-13 (not inserted automatically)
```

Comment: Masoud, if you want to force your application to resist inserting records with duplicate DraftID && UserID && Date, take a look at my solution (answer) below. Otherwise, make your question a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the existance of a record with the same TrackID, DraftID and UserID

```
tbltrackuser trackuser = new tbltrackuser();
trackuser.TrackID = 1;
trackuser.DraftID  = 20;
trackuser.UserID = "user1";
trackuser.Date = "01-jan-13";

DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

var sameRecords = from tu in dc.tbltrackusers
             where tu.DraftID == trackuser.DraftID
             && tu.UserID == trackuser.UserID
             && tu.Date == trackuser.Date
             select tu;

if (sameRecords.Count() == 0) //if there is no same record then you can insert
{
    dc.tbltrackusers.InsertOnSubmit(trackuser);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Such record already exists.");
```